# Monitor Spring Boot Apps using Prometheus on Kubernetes , not setting end Points

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, spring-boot-actuator

I am Trying to monitor Spring Boot application using Prometheus on Kubernetes. Promethus was insatll using Helm and I am using Spring Boot Actuator for  Health checking, Auditing, Metrics gathering and Monitoring.

Actuator gives details about application. For example

`http://**IP:Port**/actuator/health` return below output

```
{"status":"UP"}.
```

I use below configuration file to add the application end point in promethus.

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: scp-service-creator
  namespace: sc678
  labels:
    app: scp-service-creator
    release: prometheus-operator
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scp-service-creator
  endpoints:
  - port: api
    path: "/actuator/prometheus"
    scheme: http
    interval: 10s
    honorLabels: true
```

So my problem is even service is added to prometheus , no endpoint is assigned.
So What would be wrong here. Really appreciate your help.

[image: targets in promethus]

[image: service-discovery in promethus]

Thank You.

Comment: Can you provide prometheus `.yaml`?

Comment: no such file used. Prometheus was installed via Helm.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spring Boot Actuator documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/), to be more specific the [Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) part. One can read that Endpoints are enabled be default except `Shutdown` which is disabled, but only `health` and `info` are exposed.

This can be checked [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints).

You need to expose the Endpoint you want manually.

The Endpoint you want to use which is `Prometheus` is Not Available for JMX and is disabled for Web.

> To change which endpoints are exposed, use the following technology-specific  `include`  and  `exclude`  properties:
>
> Property | Default
>
> `management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude` |
>
> `management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include` | *
>
> `management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude` |
>
> `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` | `info, health`
>
> The  `include`  property lists the IDs of the endpoints that are exposed. The  `exclude`  property lists the IDs of the endpoints that should not be exposed. The  `exclude`property takes precedence over the  `include`  property. Both  `include`  and  `exclude`  properties can be configured with a list of endpoint IDs.
>
> For example, to stop exposing all endpoints over JMX and only expose the  `health`  and  `info`  endpoints, use the following property:
>
> `management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=health,info`
>
> `*`  can be used to select all endpoints. For example, to expose everything over HTTP except the  `env`  and  `beans`  endpoints, use the following properties:
>
> `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`
>   `management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=env,beans`